# CakePHP: "add" action doesn't work with admin prefix

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Before adding admin prefixes/routing, everything was working fine...

Currently, I have a QuestionsController.php file with the following function:

```
public function admin_add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post') ) {
        $this->Question->create();
        if ($this->Question->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your question has been saved.');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to add your question.');
        }
    } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Not post.');
    }

}
```

Here is the contents of /views/Questions/admin_add.php:

```
<h2>Add a question</h2>
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Question');
echo $this->Form->input('nickname');
echo $this->Form->input('content');
echo $this->Form->input('option1');
echo $this->Form->input('option2');
echo $this->Form->input('option3');
echo $this->Form->end('Save question');

echo $this->Html->link('Cancel', array('controller' => 'questions', 'action' => 'index'));
```

Notice the setFlash("Not post.") at the bottom of the controller? Every time I click the "Save question" button I see that message? Why?

**UPDATE**
We've determine that the request method is `get`, which explains why it's not working. But now the real question is *why* is it `get`. I'm pretty sure it was `post` before adding the admin prefix.

Comment: temporarily, you can just check if `if(!empty($this->request->data)) {` - though that doesn't answer your question as to why.

Comment: is your form method POST?

Comment: @Dave Good idea! `$this->request->data` is in fact empty. Any idea why?

Comment: @BarryChapman I thought so but the fact that it's not working suggests otherwise.

Comment: You are using admin prefixes right? and not admin routing?

Comment: @BarryChapman Yes. My functions are definitely prefixed with `admin_`. Although there may also be some routing elsewhere (I'm not the only dev on this project).

Comment: @BarryChapman I dug into the app/Config/core file and I found this: ` Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin'));
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Question', array( 'type' => 'POST' ) ); ?>
```

Try that :)

You can also add other options to that `$options` array, such as action, encoding, defaults, url, etc.

**UPDATE**

From your comments, I think you are telling us that the GET is determined from the controller. Examine your FORM in your source code to see if `type="post"` is there, or if it says `type="get"`.

If it is posting, then you are being redirected on post, similar to a [PRG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern. This is where you are losing it. What URL do you ultimately end up on after POST'ing your form?

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Still GET

Comment: In the source code the form's method is post. I don't know the PRG pattern. Can you elaborate a bit on what's going on? Also, did you see my response to your comment above about the admin routing in the Config/core.php file? Is that route clashing with the `admin_` prefixes?

Comment: PRG = Post-Redirect-Get. You are redirecting on POST to your controller. My assumption that your user is not authenticated to POST to an admin action? I could be wrong, but it essentially it is taking your POST parameters and converting them to GET (Or not at all, just simply redirecting you). Are you using any other plugins?

Comment: I haven't installed other plugins, but I am a bit shaky on the relationship between admin prefixes and the Auth->allow/deny, so it's possible that I'm screwing something up. However, I am able to trigger  an Auth->redirect consistently, and that's not happening here. Just reloading the same page.

Comment: I just noticed another detail that I didn't think was relevant. My CakePHP app is located in a subdirectory /_cake/ but I have mod_rewrite rules which rewrite urls to remove the /_cake/. If I use developer tools to change the form action to NOT include the _cake/ part of the url, the method is POST. So it seems that the mod_rewrite is having an effect. I'm not sure why though.

Comment: That was it. The mod_rewrite rules were somehow interfering with the authorization. I disabled them and everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

If it's hitting the second half of the if block, the the request isn't post.

To find out WHAT it is, just add this code just before the if block:

```
debug(CakeRequest::method());
```

(assuming your debug level is 2 for development mode)

Then, once you know what kind of request is happening, check against that.

Comment: It's `GET`! Weird!! Do you have any idea why that would be?